# cumulative distribution function method transformation

Tags: probability, transformation

Suppose that $X$ has a uniform distribution on the interval $(−1, 1)$ with probability density
function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1/2 & \text{for }− 1 < x < 1 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

Q1: Use the cumulative distribution function (cdf) method to first find the cdf of 
$Y = x^2$ and hence determine the probability density function of $Y$.

Q2: Sketch the pdf of $Y$

Ans: I think I know how to do this for the interval $(0,1)$ but amn't sure what changes when the interval is different

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at both links [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and for formatting [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First consider $P(Y \leq y)$ as usual. Now if you have $a^2<0.5$ what can you say about possible values of $a$? Try applying similar approach.